# Web service auto-redirection to http or https

Tags: c#, web-services, wcf

I have just updated a C# web service client from the old web-services, to the newer service, I believe it's called WCF?  In the old webservices, there was a property for AllowAutoRedirect, to automatically redirect from http to https.  It didn't work well, but there was also a Url property, so if the connection failed on http, I could write code to change the URL to https and try again.

In the new WCF method, is there a way to do this?  Would I have to add a reference to a second service, with the same address, but https?

(I have turned SSL on my website on and off a few times in the past, and it's necessary for my software out in the field to automatically handle this, and use whichever is available).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this by adding rewrite rules. This will rewrite any incoming request from HTTP to HTTPS. You can check these posts below to find the solution.

```
<rule name="Redirect to HTTPS" stopProcessing="true">
  <match url="(.*)" />
  <conditions>
    <add input="{HTTPS}" pattern="^OFF$" />
  </conditions>
  <action type="Redirect" url="https://{HTTP_HOST}/{R:1}" redirectType="Permanent" />
</rule>
```

[IIS redirect/rewrite .asmx service](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45937254/iis-redirect-rewrite-asmx-service)
[wcf webservice and URL forwarding with https](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27496289/wcf-webservice-and-url-forwarding-with-https)  
[HttpClient doesn't redirect even when AllowAutoRedirect = true](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42405183/httpclient-doesnt-redirect-even-when-allowautoredirect-true) 
[Can i use a 301 redirect to allow an existing .Net Web service to keep functioning without requiring client updates?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40404829/can-i-use-a-301-redirect-to-allow-an-existing-net-web-service-to-keep-functioni)

Comment: Great idea.  I hadn't thought to do in on the server.  This is a much better solution, thanks.